# You have requested a non-existent service "profiler"

Tags: symfony

I want enable Production on my website, but after executing command: `composer dump-env prod`

I am getting this error, when want clear cache:

```
In ContainerBuilder.php line 992:
                                                         
  You have requested a non-existent service "profiler".
```

Symfony version: latest (6.3)
PHP Version: 8.2

btw. I tried search google already..

If you want see any config or settings, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Weird, I am removed

`Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Profiler\Profiler: '@profiler'`

From `services.yaml` and its works.

Comment: in symfony better practice is change mode in .env.local, symfony dont know your mode without that. You just removed profiler package in vendor and tried clear cache in symfony dev mode.

Comment: I have used this https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html